# double timestamp in dataframe merge

Tags: r, utc, zoo

I do have a df looking like this:

```
time,v1,v1,v3,v4
1352639505, , ,94,101
1352639565, , ,94,101
1352639505,10,222, ,
1352639565,11,221, ,
```

First one is UTC Timestamp from 1970-01-01 - so I would use
`as.POSIXct(df$time,origin="1970-01-01",tz="UTC")`. But as you can see date is double. NAs and values are skipped. How to merge the same date in the dataframe? First setting as.POSIXct or merging?

Result should look like this:

```
time,v1,v1,v3,v4
1352639505,10,222,94,101
1352639565,11,221,94,101
```

Of course it could also be zoo afterwads with real date!
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would treat each column of your data.frame individually.  For each column, drop the missing observations from the column and the time index, then construct your `zoo` object.  Then you can use `do.call` to call `merge` on your list of `zoo` objects.

```
# helper function to build zoo objects with no missing values
f <- function(v, i) {
  na <- is.na(v)
  iposix <- as.POSIXct(i, origin="1970-01-01", tz="UTC")
  zoo(v[!na], iposix[!na])
}
df <- structure(list(time = c(1352639505L, 1352639565L, 1352639505L, 
1352639565L), v1 = c(NA, NA, 10L, 11L), v1 = c(NA, NA, 222L, 
221L), v3 = c(94L, 94L, NA, NA), v4 = c(101L, 101L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("time", 
"v1", "v1", "v3", "v4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
library(zoo)
Data <- do.call(merge, lapply(df[-1], f, i=df$time))
Data
#                     v1 v1.1 v3  v4
# 2012-11-11 07:11:45 10  222 94 101
# 2012-11-11 07:12:45 11  221 94 101
```

Comment: +1 Imaginative solution. Trying to wrap my head around the `do.call`

Comment: @SimonO101: `do.call` creates and evaluates a function call using the function and a (named) list of arguments. In this case, it constructs something like `merge(v1, v1.1, v3, v4)`.